# Angular SwUpdate.activated not triggered

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular project, a PWA.
Inside my AppComponent OnInit, I register to `available` and `activated` events of Angular ServiceWorker:

```
    import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
    
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      
      ...
      constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {}

      public ngOnInit(): void {
        
        ...

        if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      
          this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('available');
          });

          this.swUpdate.activated.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('activated');
          });

        }
      }
    }
```

The available part works, then I refresh and get the new version.

But then I expect the activated part will trigger and it's not.
Did I incorrectly understand the activated observable?

(BTW, my goal is to display a "what's new" popup after the user refreshes and gets the new version, so if you have a different solution other than using the `activated` observable, it would also help).

Thanks